# How can I solve membership and respons.redirect()

Tags: asp.net

I implemented membership, and when users loging, I call this code:

```
 if (Membership.ValidateUser(txtUsern.Text, txtPass.Text))
    {
        string[] rol = Roles.GetRolesForUser(txtUsern.Text);

        string s = rol[0];
        DetectRoll(s);

    }
```

and it is DetectRoll(); function:

```
switch (s)
    {
        case "manager":
            Response.Redirect("~/Manager/Manager.aspx");
            break;
        case "operator":
            Response.Redirect("~/Operator/Operator.aspx");
            break;
        case "user":
            Response.Redirect("~/User/User.aspx");
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
```

problem is that Respons.Redirect() don't move me to typical Page.

web.config in master folder

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <configuration> 
  <system.web> 
    <authorization> 
     <allow roles="manager" /> 
     <deny users="*" /> 
   </authorization> 
  </system.web> 
</configuration>
```

please help, thank you.........

Comment: So what page does it move to?

Comment: non page. it stay in login.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You need to call,

```
System.Web.Security
   .FormsAuthentication
   .SetAuthCookie("role_Name",bool_persistentCookie)
```

method before you call `Response.Redirect()`.

EDIT:

Modify web.config file's `<deny/>` entry.

`<deny users="?"/>`

Anonymous users are identified using a question mark (`?`). You can specify all authenticated users using an asterisk (`*`).

Comment: I wrote your code but it dose not solve my problem, do u have idea?

Comment: Please post the `web.config` code located under Manager, Operator and User folders (any one).

Comment: '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <configuration>
   <system.web>
    <authorization>
      <allow roles="manager" />
      <deny users="*" />
    </authorization>
    </system.web> 
    </configuration>'

Comment: @user1492770 Use `<deny users="?"/>` instead of `<deny users="*" />`

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried;

```
Response.Redirect(ResolveURL("~/Manager/Manager.aspx"));
```